# CSS Card Flip and Text

Tags: html, css, text, css-animations

I am designing my website and I have run into a problem. I put a CSS Card flip effect. It works almost perfectly but when it is flipped. The text will flash, then vanish (go behind div).

The different problems in the browsers:

Chrome: Flickering
Safari: Hiding behind the `<div>`

[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/blue1086/vnk0u9xb/)

```
#container {
    -webkit-perspective: 800;
}
.flip {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
    background-color: red;
    height: 5em;
    width: 5em;
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 6em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.flip > img {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 5em;
}
.flip:hover{ -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg); }
.flip > *{
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    position:absolute;
}
.flip > div{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    text-align:center;
    height: 5em;
    width: 5em;
}
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vnk0u9xb/3/ JSFiddle with standard CSS code added to the `-webkit-` stuff. Seems to work fine for me with the text, but I have rewritten a selector and a rule so that the `:hover` applies to the container as opposed to the red circle as the mouse temporarily leaves the red circle as it rotates. Is this what you’re looking for or does the text still get rendered incorrectly?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vnk0u9xb/4/ This is another version where I made the `#container` a circle as well, so that the mouse would actually only trigger the circle area. Works perfectly fine for me in Firefox 36.0.4.

Comment: @Xufox Text is flickering for me on both fiddles (chrome 41.0.2272.101 m)

Comment: @Xufox Weird, works flawlessly in Firefox, text doesn't show in Safari, and in Chrome it flickers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When constructing objects in 3D, it's always a good idea to avoid a situation that is known as z-fighting. This happens when 2 elements share (exactly) the same plane, so that the rendering engine doesn't know wich is in front of the other. The result can be flickering images, or also mixed images (part of one image and part of the other)

The usual way to solve this in 2d, zindex, won't solve this issue. You need to solve it in 3D space.

In you case, the solution would be

move the image 1 px in z to the front:

```
.flip>img {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(1px) translateY(-50%);
}
```

move the div 1px to the back:

```
.flip>div{
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1px) rotateY(180deg);
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vnk0u9xb/7/)

Comment: Oh wow, can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks for the help